# Smooth animation transition logic in Android OpenGL

Tags: android, animation, libgdx

I have an Android app developed using openGL and LibGDX.
Right now I do not know the strategy on how to code smooth transitions among a set of animations.

Example:

We have a `cat` actor.
Its animation consists of a set of key frames paired with transform matrix.
We have 5 preset animations for this `cat`:
`idle`, `walk left`, `walk right`, `jump` and `lie down`.

How can we transition from lets say
`walk right` => `lie down`
`walk right` => `walk left`
while the `walk right` animation is playing half way?

Right now once an animation starts, it needs to be played for 1 full cycle until the end.
This is so that the `cat` can move back into its neutral position.
Thus it can play the next animation which starts from a neutral position.
The final result is unnatural and jerky.

What approach should I use to tackle this problem?

Comment: I don't know how you implemented. Could you put your part of codes here for view?

Answer (score 1):

Just starting the next Animation even when the previous one isn't finished is the Standard way. It looks good, do not wait for the first Animation to finish.

If you still think it looks unnatural. Then you must create a very fast "transition frame" between animations that makes it look more natural. Not worth the effort if you ask me, just try it the first way :)